# Dojo - check if event is connected

Tags: dojo

is there a way to check if an item has already an event handler connected ?

like:

```
if (!isconnected(item)) {
  dojo.connect(item, 'onclick', doSomething());
}
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!itemConnected)
    itemConnected = dojo.connect(item, 'onclick', doSomething())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the simple solution `item.connected`